# Notice: Undefined Index inside 'while loop'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

What are the reason for these errors to be appearing?

```
Notice: Undefined index: photo
Notice: Undefined index: username
```

They are appearing inside the while loop, on '.$row['photo'].' and '.$row['username'].'

I'm just calling the public function on the PHP page as followed.

```
<?php echo $userSuggestions($uiD); ?>
```

---

The reason why I need it inside the while loop is that I'm trying to use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC so it does not repeat the same results when echoed.

I'm able to make it work with just `$row = $sth->fetch()` then on the php page calling it as followed: `$userSuggestions['photo'], $userSuggestions['Username']` but that way I won't be able to loop it and retrieve different results(different information instead of repeating same one over and over).

I've searched various threads to come to the conclusion that isset() is needed, but unable to understand why isset is needed inside this query, if anyone able to explain I'd appreciate it. **Thank you.**

```
public function userSuggestions($uiD)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("
                                SELECT F.friend_two AS possible_friend, U.username, U.uiD, U.photo
                                FROM user_friends F, users U
                                WHERE F.friend_one IN (SELECT friend_two FROM user_friends WHERE friend_one = :uiD) 
                                AND F.friend_two NOT IN (SELECT friend_two FROM user_friends WHERE friend_one = :uiD)
                                AND NOT F.friend_two = :uiD
                                AND U.uiD NOT IN (SELECT friend_two FROM user_friends WHERE friend_one = :uiD) 
                                AND U.photo NOT IN (SELECT friend_two FROM user_friends WHERE friend_one = :uiD) 
                                GROUP BY possible_friend
                                ORDER BY RAND()
                                ");
    $sth->execute(array(':uiD' => $uiD));

    while($row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '
                <div class="SuggestionsPhotoDiv">
                    <img src="'.$row['photo'].'" class="SuggestionsPhoto">

                    <span class="SuggestionsButton">
                        <a>Follow Me</a>
                    </span>

                    <span class="SuggestionsName">
                        <a>'.$row['username'].'</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
        ';      return $row;

    }
```

Comment: It means on the row it is iterating over, those items don't exist in the $row array. try var_dump($row) at the beginning of the while loop to troubleshoot it.

Comment: That's funny, if I do var_dump($row); inside the loop I get photo and username arrays returned but when I try ti print it it gives me the error.

Comment: @iBrazilian - would you be able to post an excerpt of the `var_dump()` so we can see what's being returned?

Comment: @Joe I've seen your answer, and thank you for replying. Inside the while loop it returns the username and photo but when I print it, it does not work and gives undefined index.

array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["possible_friend"]=> string(3) "154" ["username"]=> string(5) "Emily" ["uiD"]=> string(3) "151" ["photo"]=> string(96) "uploads/profilePictures/image2.jpg" } [1]=> array(4) { ["possible_friend"]=> string(3) "153" ["username"]=> string(5) "Emily" ["uiD"]=> string(3) "151" ["photo"]=> string(96) "uploads/profilePictures/image1.jpg" } }

Comment: @iBrazilian - thanks for posting that! It's simply an issue with you using `fetchAll` instead of `fetch`. Either of the solutions in my answer will work but the first one should be faster to implement.

Comment: I tried both your solutions and they're correct, thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // your current code here
}
```

This uses `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`. `fetchAll` returns an array of *all* the results meaning that when you try to access `$row['username']` it doesn't exist.

**Solution 2:**

```
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row){
    // your current code here
}
```

This gets the output as an array of arrays then loops through them.

The `fetchAll` function documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Here's your `fetchAll` output:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(4) {
        ["possible_friend"]=> string(3)"154"
        ["username"]=> string(5) "Emily"
        ["uiD"]=> string(3) "151"
        ["photo"]=> string(96) "uploads/profilePictures/image2.jpg"
    }
    [1]=> array(4) {
        ["possible_friend"]=> string(3) "153"
        ["username"]=> string(5) "Emily"
        ["uiD"]=> string(3) "151"
        ["photo"]=> string(96) "uploads/profilePictures/image1.jpg"
    }
}
```

You can see that it's outputting all results so the `username` key doesn't exist in the top level array.